# Is there a clean way to split comma-and-space--separated words using ranges?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++17, range-v3, std-ranges

I'm actually adapting this one from [a deleted question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67378872/5825294).

**Input:** a string containing comma separated words with space after the commas.

**Output:** the words.

By "clean" I mean something that doesn't rely on storing temporaries into variables which wouldn't have a reason to exist, based on the intent of the code.

My attempt

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/view/split.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/split_when.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/transform.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/trim.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

auto constexpr is = [](char c){
    return [c](char c_){ return c_ == c; };
};
using namespace ranges::views;

int main()
{
  std::string ss{"cccccciao"};
  // correctly prints [i,a,o]
  std::cout << (ss | trim(is('c'))) << std::endl;

  std::string s = "blue, green, red";
  std::cout << split_when(s, is(',')) << std::endl;

  std::vector<std::string> vs;
  vs.push_back(ss);
  vs.push_back(ss);
  // correctly prints [[i,a,o],[i,a,o]]
  std::cout << (vs | transform(trim(is('c')))) << std::endl;

  // doesn't work
  //auto result0 = split_when(s, is(',')) | transform(trim(is(' ')));
  //auto result1 = transform(split_when(s, is(',')), trim(is(' ')));

  // doesn't work either
  auto sss = split_when(s, [](char c){ return c == ','; });
  //auto result2 = transform(sss, trim([](char c){ return c == ' '; }));
  //auto result3 = sss | transform(trim([](char c){ return c == ' '; }));
}
```

Based on the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) I expected that something like this oneliner should work,

```cpp
auto result0 = s | split_when(is(',')) | transform(trim(is(' ')));
```

but it doesn't.

Comment: Can the words be space separated as well? If not, you could just split twice.

Comment: @cigien, can you make an example?

Comment: I was thinking about something like `split(' ') | join | split(',')` but I just tried it, and that example doesn't work.

Comment: Why not a `ranges::for_each` and remove (erase) the space and then use `split_when()`?

Comment: Like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/s55z8zPEq) ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split` can split on a pattern that is longer than one element. The one caveat is that `", "`, considered as a range, is a pattern of three elements (including the terminating null character) - and in any event the adapter decays it to a pointer, which makes it not-a-range. So:

```cpp
auto result = input | rv::split(", "sv);
```

Comment: This is very elegant; I forgot split can take a range.